# How to add a note below a table that doesn't exceed the table dimensions?

Tags: beamer, pdftex, pdf, rmarkdown

I am writing a paper in Rmarkdown. I created a table and I would like to place a note belowe the table. The problem is that when I try to do so, being the note quite long, it exceeds table's dimensions and makes the table impossible to read.

My code is:

```
\begin{table}[H]
\centering 
\caption{"Save The Euro" Factor} 
\label{tab: fig2} 
\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{5pt}} cc} 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
 & Factor 2 \\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
$Variance Share$ (\%) & 13.7\\
$Loadings$:\\
OIS 1M & $-$0.030 \\ 
OIS 1Y & 0.060 \\ 
OIS 2Y & 0.065 \\ 
Germany 2Y yield & 0.048 \\ 
Germany 5Y yield & 0.079  \\ 
Germany 10Y yield  & 0.115 \\
France 2Y yield & 0.061 \\
France 5Y yield & 0.019 \\
France 10Y yield & 0.003 \\
Italy 2Y yield & $-$0.286 \\ 
Italy 5Y yield & $-$0.340 \\
Italy 10Y yield & $-$0.336 \\ 
Spain 2Y yield & $-$0.236 \\ 
Spain 5Y yield & $-$0.305 \\ 
Spain 10Y yield & $-$0.330 \\ 
STOXX50E Index & 0.348 \\ 
SX7E (Bank) Index  & 0.384  \\ 
Euro-Dollar & 0.032  \\ 
EUR-Pound & 0.018  \\ 
EUR-Yen & 0.107  \\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex]
\footnotesize{\textit{Note}: The figure shows the estimated DFPA. The frequency has been increased to quarterly observation to improve readability. The vertical blue lines correspond to intervention in the secondary market, while the vertical light-blue line indicates the ruling of the ECJ. Above 0 indicates a *dovish* score, while below 0 a *hawkish* one.}
\end{tabular} 
\end{table}
```

I just would like the note to fit table's dimensions. Can anyone help me?

Thanks!

Comment: please always post test documents so we can see the issue. Note that size commands do not take an argument so `\footnotesize` not `\footnotesize{`  Just move the text after the `tabular` with a blank line in between: you currently have it all in one line in just the first cell of the last row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

One way is to use threeparttable

I have not used the data from your table since its an extra effort

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,caption}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \begin{threeparttable}
    \caption{Sample ANOVA table}
     \begin{tabular}{lllll}
        \toprule
        Stubhead & \( df \) & \( f \) & \( \eta \) & \( p \) \\
        \midrule
                 &     \multicolumn{4}{c}{Spanning text}     \\
        Row 1    & 1        & 0.67    & 0.55       & 0.41    \\
        Row 2    & 2        & 0.02    & 0.01       & 0.39    \\
        Row 3    & 3        & 0.15    & 0.33       & 0.34    \\
        Row 4    & 4        & 1.00    & 0.76       & 0.54    \\
        \bottomrule
     \end{tabular}
    \begin{tablenotes}
      \small
      \item This is where authors provide additional information about
      the data, including whatever notes are needed.
    \end{tablenotes}
  \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Thanks to @JosephWright for this solution